# Run CIFAR10 eval script with one GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run the CIFAR10 training + eval scripts from the TensorFlow tutorial.
I have only one GPU.
Is it possible to do so? Maybe make the eval script run somehow on the CPU?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""` before running the eval script

Comment: Could you give more context? What have you tried so far and why it is not working?